# How to refresh token without getting having to go through auth again? OAuth2

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

How to refresh the access token without having to go through the authentication process again with OAuth2??

Right now if fetch user fails, I will do refresh token, but in order to do refresh token I must first receive a 401 unauthorized error.

By the time I receive the 401 after not being able to do a request, i redirect to the login screen because if i dont redirect to the login screen, the subsequent requests will just not show up.

IF i used an expiration time, the token wouldn't refresh without first doing a request, but by the time the request is made the token had already expired.

What i am asking is what is the logic that i should use for refreshing access tokens so my app won't log out everytime the token expires and require another authentication.

I would like my app to function more like facebook or google where you stay logged in until you log out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you let me know what type of app and tech stack you are using?

There are two times:

- Access token lifetime - a short lived API credential (eg 60 minutes)
- User session lifetime (usually represented by a refresh token - eg 12 hours)

There are mechanisms to silently renew tokens client side. The general approach is to get a new token and retry the API call when you get a 401 due to access token expired, as in [this class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/apiClient.ts) of mine.

How you get a new token depends on the type of app (mobile / SPA / cookie based web app)

Comment: Thanks for the link, i think this is what i am looking for, i will make sure after this reply. 

I am making a mobile app using fetch to call and react native expo for the app (no typescript)

Comment: Refresh token wasn't working due to it being not application/json, thanks this is what i was looking for

Comment: is there something like this for javascript(not typescript)? preferably with fetch

Comment: The correct github link: https://github.com/gary-archer/authguidance.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/apiClient.ts

Comment: But how to implement `refresh token` from back-end side? Should I use 3rd party framework?